# Yii2 - Using multiple models of same class on the same activeform

Tags: php, yii2, active-form

Following the instructions from http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/666/handling-tabular-data-loading-and-validation-in-yii-2/, I have done the following:

From my controller, I passed in an array $accessibleDepts that contains an array of models of class DeptEmployee.

In my view, I add these models to my active form like so:

```
foreach($accessibleDepts as $i=>$accessibleDept){
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<h5>' . $accessibleDept->deptGroupName . '</h5>';
    echo $form->errorSummary($accessibleDept); 


    echo $form->field($accessibleDept, '[$i]ACTIVE_FLAG')->checkbox(['value'=>-1]);
    echo $form->field($accessibleDept, '[$i]DEPT_START')->textInput(['readonly'=>false, 'class' => 'datepicker']); 
    echo $form->field($accessibleDept, '[$i]COMMENTS')->textarea(['readonly'=>false, 'style' => 'width:500px; height:150px']); 
}
```

If I pass in two models in $accessibleDepts, I see both models displayed on my form the way I expect. However, when I submit the form as a post request, I see that the post object I am sending for the DeptEmployee class models is only including the second model.

It looks like

```
[
    '$i' => [
        'ACTIVE_FLAG' => '-1',
        'DEPT_START' => '23-JUN-2017',
        'COMMENTS' => 'TEST COMMENT',
    ]
]
```

I'm not sure why $i is not being converted to an index here, it seems like only the last model of class DeptEmployee is being kept and sent back to the controller.

The $accessibleDepts array is created in my controller like so

```
$deptEmployeeQuery = DeptEmployee::find()->where(['EMP_ID'=>$emp_id]);
if($deptEmployeeQuery->count() > 0){
    $deptEmployeeArray = $deptEmployeeQuery->all();
}

foreach($deptEmployeeArray as $deptRecord){
    if ($this->authModel->hasAccessToDeptGroup($deptRecord['DEPT_GROUP_ID']))
        $accessibleDepts[] = $deptRecord;
}

if(DeptEmployee::loadMultiple($accessibleDepts, Yii::$app->request->post())){
    return $this->render('success');
}
```

Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `view` as below:

```
foreach($accessibleDepts as $i=>$accessibleDept){
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<h5>' . $accessibleDept->deptGroupName . '</h5>';
    echo $form->errorSummary($accessibleDept); 


    echo $form->field($accessibleDept, "[$i]ACTIVE_FLAG")->checkbox(['value'=>-1]);
    echo $form->field($accessibleDept, "[$i]DEPT_START")->textInput(['readonly'=>false, 'class' => 'datepicker']); 
    echo $form->field($accessibleDept, "[$i]COMMENTS")->textarea(['readonly'=>false, 'style' => 'width:500px; height:150px']); 
}
```

Single quotation marks will depress variables to be interpreted. For more detail, you may go [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)